# How to manage static assets in a python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module

I am working on a python module to act as a testing library, I am thinking of exposing it as a web service for load testing the backend, and as a cli for running manual tests

I don't know how to manage static test files, for example the project looks like:

```
web/
cmd/
src/
  test_data/
  library.py
```

What is your advice for loading the test_data ? I thought of putting test_data outside of the module, but they would be duplicated a lot.

Should I use relative paths in library.py ?

```
test_file = f'{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/test_data/file.txt'
```

Comment: also the library might be submoduled